# MySQL Вызов хранимой процедуры из другой хранимой процедуры

Tags: mysql

Имеются две хранимые процедуры

1 процедура

```
CREATE DEFINER=`******`@`******` 
PROCEDURE `add_row_into_number_docs`(IN `dealer` INT, IN `docTypeId` INT)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
  COMMENT ''
num_docs:BEGIN
```

Не буду приводить весь код, так как он большой. Отмечу только то, что он должен в результате выдать переменную result, которая принимает значение 0 или 1

```
select result;
END
```

2 процедура

```
CREATE DEFINER=`******`@`******` PROCEDURE `oparation`(IN `dealer` INT, IN `docTypeId` INT)
  LANGUAGE SQL
  DETERMINISTIC
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER
  COMMENT ''
num_docs:BEGIN
```

Так же не буду приводить весь код. В этой процедуре вызывается 1 процедура

```
call  add_row_into_number_docs(userDealerId,docTypeId);
```

И далее идут опять некоторые манипуляции. Данная процедура должна вернуть результат:

```
select resultCode, resultComment, idKOOperation;
END
```

Но почему-то, при вызове второй процедуры, получаю результат, который возвращает 1 процедура

```
result
```

Вместо ожидаемых

```
resultCode, resultComment, idKOOperation
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Если вы просто написали select внутри хранимой процедуры, это не имеет никакого отношения к возврату значений с хранимой процедуры. Для возврата результата используются OUT параметры, которых у Вас нет.

Comment: ок, согласен.  но пока не использовал первую процедуру все работало прекрасно и так же пробовал использовать OUT параметры, только после их введения получаю ошибку 'Ошибка SQL (1318): Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE oparation; expected 9, got 6 '

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается есть определенные нюансы работы с выходными параметрами. Разобрался.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: при вызове хранимой процедуры я указывал только IN параметры, Оказывается еще нужно было указать  переменные в которых будут сохраняться выходные параметры. В моем случае  процедуру `oparation`(IN `dealer` INT, IN `docTypeId` OUT resultCode INT)  нужно было вызывать call `operation` (1,1,@a) а я в начале вызывал указав просто входные параметры call `operation` (1,1,)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите передавать значение из одной процедуры в другую, лучше вместо хранимых процедур использовать хранимые функции. В этом случае вы сможете передавать

```
CREATE DEFINER=`******`@`******`
FUNCTION `add_row_into_number_docs`(IN `dealer` INT, IN `docTypeId` INT)
  RETURNS INT
  READS SQL DATA
  COMMENT ''
num_docs:BEGIN
...
  RETURN result;
END
```

Тогда внутри хранимой процедуры `oparation` вы сможете получить значение из функции `add_row_into_number_docs`, присвоив его значению какой-нибудь переменной.

```
SET resultNumberCode := add_row_into_number_docs(userDealerId, docTypeId);
```

Если вы хотите сохранить `oparation` в виде хранимой процедуры, тогда результат можно включить в результирующий SELECT-запрос

```
SELECT resultCode, resultComment, idKOOperation, resultNumberCode;
```